# Difference between File.Replace and (File.Delete+File.Move) in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Today I ran into a strange problem: Since a year and several versions / tests of the application the following code has been used successfully to replace a file with an other.

```
File.Replace(path + ".tmp", path, null);
```

This has worked locally and also with UNC paths (network shares). But today I got the following error when I used this code to replace a file on a UNC path (local still works):

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

When I use the following code instead of the above, it works:

```
File.Delete(path);
File.Move(path + ".tmp", path);
```

So my questions:

- What is the difference between the two code snippets?
- Could it be that Microsoft have changed the way 'File.Replace' works?

I'm using .Net Framework 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't happen to have one of these uber-eager 'security tools' running on the server, messing up in their 'on access protection' or something, right? Does this happen with every server? Did it stop working at a specific date and - what happened on the server at that point in time?

Comment: thx for your answer: we don't have a special "über" security tool and haven't changed the infrastructure since a while. The problem also appears on other machines in other networks. I don't know the date exactly but I would say before February 2011 it has worked...

Comment: `File.Replace` demands read and write permission on both source and destination, then p/invokes `ReplaceFile`. Check the docs on `ReplaceFile` for clues. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365512.aspx

Comment: We can only guess - it should work. As Tergiver says, the method doesn't do anything special. And you are sure that your code (that, I assume, wrote to *.tmp) closed that file? Because again, as Tergiver says, read and write permissions for _both files_ are requested. First. Before anything happens in that method. Missing a Dispose maybe for your writer? What I'm trying to say is: Don't focus too much on the target file. Both could be the problem (unless the error explicitly refers to the target).

Comment: I checked the disposing/closing of all my other actions on both files and no - there are no missing dispose/close...

Answer (score 8):

According to [MSDN on File.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.replace.aspx)

File.Replace will throw an exception when...

- the **destination** file is missing.
- source and destination are on different volumes

Which File.Delete, File.Move won't.

Comment: so if source and destination are on different volumes, it will throw an exception? What the hell is that for a implementation... thanks for the link!

Comment: @dataCore The purpose of `Replace` is to replace the file. When using Move + Delete, you just create a new file. Replace preserves security attributes, alternate data streams, file ID, encryption, compression, creation date etc. Note that the only reason that `File.Move` works accross volumes is that it specifically implements that functionality by falling back to Copy+Delete - the underlying winapi MoveFile doesn't allow  moving files between volumes, for obvious reasons (moving file on one volume is an act of changing the path to the file, there is no copying involved).

Answer (score 4):

Here's the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.replace.aspx) on `File.Replace()`

Creating a backup of the original appears to be the difference.

Comment: Thx for your answer. You mean cause I don't specify a backup path? I still don't get it... earlier it has worked. *Edit: I tried with a backup path - still the same error message